# .NET MVC var in controller is returning incorrect results

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What the heck am I missing here. I'm having an issue adding variables to a MVC Model:

```
var clientnumber returns the correct value (ex. 123)
var companyname returns the correct value  (ex. foo)
var blah returns "System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult" for both the clientnumber 
and companyname
```

CONTROLLER:

```
var clientnumber = GetClientNumber().ToString();
var companyname = GetCompanyName().ToString();

var blah = new UserExperience { client_number = clientnumber, us_name = 
companyname };

MYSQL.UserExperiences.Add(blah);
MYSQL.SaveChanges();
```

MODEL:

```
`public partial class UserExperience
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string client_number { get; set; }
        public string us_name { get; set; }
    }`
```

Comment: How specifically have you confirmed the values you're seeing?  What are those methods you're calling and what do they return?  It sounds like you're basing your assertion on a false assumption somewhere.

Comment: I'm just watching them in debug mode in visual studio. And "System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult" gets inserted into the database.

Comment: Let's look at this another way... If `GetClientNumber()` returns a string value then why do you need to call `.ToString()` on it?  Remove the `.ToString()` calls.  That is very likely to help you discover the nature of the problem.

Comment: Make sure client_number and us_name are returning correct values. I created sample of above code and it looks fine to me. https://dotnetfiddle.net/qrS59I So it must be your values which are incorrect.

Comment: It's really weird. When I set clientnumber and companyname I do get the correct results returned. But on the next line when I set blah UserExperience and look at their values, kablam: "System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult"

Comment: Their values change to "System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult" on the line when I try to create the blah UserExperience

Comment: @zanq: Then clearly your `GetClientNumber()` and `GetCompanyName()` methods aren't returning what you assume they're returning.  There's nothing "really weird" about that.  Stop making assumptions and start debugging.  It seems *highly likely* that those methods are not returning strings at all, but are instead returning `System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your methods `GetClientNumber` and `GetCompanyName` aren't returning what you think they're returning.  Your biggest clue to this is the use of `.ToString()`.  After all, if (as you assume) they are returning string values then why would you need to call `.ToString()` on them?

They're returning `System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult` objects.  And the default string representation of an object is its class name.

We can't see those methods or anything about them, but it seems like they're not the methods you want to use here.  They're likely controller actions.  You don't want a `ContentResult`, you want a string value.  Instead of calling other MVC controller actions, invoke whatever logic you need to get the value that those actions are also getting.

Comment: Yeah, I went took a look, your correct. They were returning return Content(ClientNumber);    Thank you.